# Convert a given string into a sorted string by using minimum operations

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, sorting

We are given an arbitrary string. Now, we can perform some operations on this string.
Any letter can be transformed to any other letter. Now, we can choose any letter from the string and transform it into any other letter. This would be called as one single operation.

How can we convert a string into a string whose letters are in sorted order using minimum number of operations as described above?

All solutions, including the *out-of-the-box* ones are welcome!

P.S.: Here's an example-

```
Given string: dcba
We can convert this string into a sorted using at least 3 operations. The generated string can be any of the following:
dddd (3 operations)
aaaa (3 operations)
cccc (3 operations)
..
etc.
```

P.P.S.: As asked by some people, I am providing my own solution here-

One of the brute force solution is to exploit recursion. When we are at a certain character index of the string, we could either not change it or change it to some other character and recursively call the function with index incremented by one. If we change the character, increment the no. of operations by 1 else just pass it as is. At each step of the recursion, we can check whether the string sorted - if yes, then update the overall minimum with current count, if it's lesser than the current count.

Comment: This is not "sorting" by any conventional definition...

Comment: Well you can solve this naively by turning all letters to the first letter. N-1 operations. Have to think about a more clever solution.

Comment: @Mohammad This is wrong, becasue the question asks for "minimal number of such moves". It's like saying we can sort an array by returning it as we got it - there is a case that it is already sorted, and then it's right - but that's about it. The question is not how to make it sorted, the question is how to make it sorted with minimal number of moves, the important output here is not the sorted string, but the number of swaps.

Comment: This can be solved by reduction to shortest-path problem, but it could be computationally expansive. What is the input's size?

Comment: @amit It is still a solution unlike your array example which is clearly different. I guess you could say I provided a bogo sort if this was an array sorting question.

Comment: @amit The given string can contain about a million letters.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote please?

Comment: @Mohammad No, it is not. the output is the minimal number of moves. this is not `n-1`, with exception of some rare cases. You also provide the wrong sort, for example for [abcd] - [aaaa] is definetly a wrong answer.

Comment: @Sankalp I didn't downvote, but lately people think that algorithmic questions are out of scope, and only questions such as "how to parse a string in java" or "why printf not working as expected" are programming related questions. This attitude is of course wrong.

Comment: @Sankalp: what have you tried so far?  What problem have you encountered getting it working?  amit: hover over the downvote button and it says *"does not show any research effort"* - there's none in this question - a statement of problem with no evidence that *any* effort was made to find or logically derive a solution.

Comment: Another naive idea, iterate through letters checking if letter N > letter N+1and if so change letter N+1 to letter N. Poor results but <= n-1 on random strings, n-1 on reverse ordered strings and 0 on ordered strings.

Comment: Seems like a kind of "Levenshtein distance" problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm

Comment: So the computational complexity to arrive at the minimum is irrelevant?

Comment: What would be the practical application of such algorithm?

Comment: @TonyD I did get my hands dirty in this problem and tried to arrive at a solution..but it was pretty expensive. One of the brute force solution is to exploit recursion. When we are at a certain character index of the string, we could either not change or change it to some other character and recursively call the function with index incremented by one. If we change the character, increment the no. of operations by 1 else just pass it as is. At each step of the recursion, we can check whether the string sorted - if yes, then update the overall minimum with current count, if it's lesser..

Comment: @Sankalp: good - by mentioning that, you ensure nobody here goes to considerable effort just to have you say "oh yeah, that's what I did too and I don't think it's good enough".

Answer (score 7):

This problem is equivalent to the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) of your string: Clearly it is optimal to leave a maximum number of letters unchanged, and those have to form an increasing subsequence. The other direction works similarly.

While LIS can be solved in O(n log n) on general sequences, you don't even need that because you have an easier special case at hand with a small alphabet size a = 26. You can use dynamic programming to solve the problem in O(n · a):

Let f(i, j) be the optimal solution for the prefix s[0..(i-1)] that ends with letter j. We have the recurrence

```
f(0, j) = 0  for j = 0..25
f(i + 1, j) = [j != s[i]] + MIN(k = 0..j, f(i, k))
```

Where [k != j] is 1 if k != j and 0 otherwise. By computing each row of the table sequentially (with increasing j), you can compute the minimum in O(1).

The final solution is MIN(j = 0..25, f(n, j)). You can construct the corresponding string by recursively following the DP states that lead to the optimal solution:

```
const int a = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
vector<array<int, a>> f;
string s = "azbzc";

void reconstruct(int i, int j) {
  if (i == 0)
    return;
  int prev_j = min_element(begin(f[i-1]), begin(f[i-1]) + j + 1) - begin(f[i-1]);
  reconstruct(i - 1, prev_j);
  cout << (char)('a' + j);
}

int main() {
  f.resize(s.size() + 1);
  int n = s.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int sol = f[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
      sol = min(sol, f[i][j]);
      f[i+1][j] = (j != s[i] - 'a') + sol;
    }
  }
  int j = min_element(begin(f[n]), end(f[n])) - begin(f[n]);
  cout << "solution: " << f[n][j] << endl;
  reconstruct(n, j);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
solution: 2
aabbc
```

Comment: Your proposed solution will not return a correct answer, I'm afraid. The return value will always be `0` since `min(k = 0...j, f(i-1, k) + k!=j)` will always be `0`.

Comment: @Sankalp Yep you're right, the base case was bogus. Should be fixed now

Comment: I still doubt that it would work correctly. How are you handling the case where the LIS can start not from index `0` and instead from some other index, say `4` for instance? You do realize that maintaining a minimum in the for loop will not help since you are maintaining it from the starting index only..

Comment: @Sankalp My code doesn't compute the LIS, it computes the solution to your problem. I.e. for input "zzzaaaaa", you get "aaaaaaaa". The start position is not explicitly encoded in the recurrence because that's not necessary. Also please note the one-based indexing I'm using for the DP state, in case that is a source of confusion. The correctness proof for the recurrence is not too hard, you can use induction on i.

Comment: @Sankalp not sure what you referring to w.r.t. the minimum, it's computed correctly from what I see, and is reset for each new DP row computation

Comment: The correct answer to the input string `fgcdeabcfgh` should be `5`, but your code is returning `7` which is, as far as I guess only due to the concern I mentioned.

Comment: @Sankalp I just checked, the output in this case is `solution: 5, aaaaaabcfgh`, which I think is correct

Comment: Could you please explain me this part of the code ? `code int j = min_element(begin(f[n]), end(f[n])) - begin(f[n]) ` begin(f[n]) will point to zeroth element in f[n] which is zero right ? Why do you have to subtract it from min_element(begin(f[n]), end(f[n]))

Comment: @Vishnu begin(f[n]) is an iterator that points to the first element of f[n]. min_element also returns an iterator, pointing to the minimal element in f[n]. We subtract the two to get the index of the minimal element in f[n].

Answer (score 0):

```
// One way is to find the max length of a pattern conforming and then total length - pattern length is the min count of changes.
// 
// Here is the code to find max length of entries as sorted.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct data_entry {
    int v;
    int w;
};

typedef struct data_entry data_t;

int
find_max_weight(const data_t *l, int cnt, int v)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int min = -1;

    l += cnt-1;

    while(cnt-- >= 0) {
        if ((l->v > min) && (l->v <= v)) {
            if (ret < l->w) {
                ret = l->w;
                min = l->v;
            }
        }
        --l;
    }
    return ret;
}

int
max_pattern_len(const char *s, int len)
{
    int i, max_len = 0;
    data_t l[len];

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        data_t *p = l + i;

        p->v = *s++;

        p->w = find_max_weight(l, i, p->v) + 1; // +1 for self

        if (max_len < p->w) {
            max_len = p->w;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("{%d, %d}\n", l[i].v, l[i].w);
    }

    return max_len;
}

int
main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char buff[100];
    int i;

    if ((argc > 1) && (argc < sizeof(buff))) {
        int max;

        for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            buff[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
        }
        max = max_pattern_len(buff, argc-1);
        printf("max_pattern_len=%d min_changes=%d\n", max, argc-1-max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```